# setup nginx secure websocket to insecure websocket proxy

Tags: nginx

We currently terminate https at nginx and forward requests over http to our backend webservers in our operation center(all webservers are on port 9000).  We would like to also proxy the secure websocket(port 443) to an insecure websocket(port 9000 which is same as our http) on the backend with NGINX.

Also, we require that the same socket ports are used 443 for websocket coming into nginx(same as https) to port 9000 for websocket coming into our webserver.

We know that our webserver already supports http and websockets both going to port 9000 and that is all working.  Now, it is just a matter of NGINX configuration so the websocket that comes in goes out with no encryption key exchange stuff going on.

Anyone know how to configure nginx for this?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: What configuration have you tried and where is it failing?

Comment: I haven't tried as the only docs I have seen seem to be on ws to ws, not wss to ws (ie. http to http where I need https to http).  Without docs, I am not even sure what to try, though I may just randomly put some stuff together and see if it works later this week.  (I was hoping not to do alot of work though without first knowing that it should work but haven't been able to prove this is possible)

Comment: This guy posted about this particular setup: http://pankajmalhotra.com/Websockets-SSL-TLS-Termination-Using-NGINX-Proxy